# Magento2 : Admin is not working, Showing error doesn't redirect properly

Tags: magento2, admin, error, memcached

I tried to setup memcached to my Magento 2 website.

**After setup setting in env.php magento admin not working(not able to see admin login page)  or some time infinite loading**

I remove setting for memcache from env.php , remove cache , upgrade setup , di compile. Every command I run but still site now working. Even no log generated

Comment: i am also getting same problem,if you solved then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the below commands from the Magento root installation

- `rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*`
- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `php bin/magento setup:di:compile`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
- `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Hope this helps